# In Python, what's the cleanest way to read from a Queue while it's not empty, and always call task_done?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I've just had a situation where a multi-threaded app I wrote was hanging at some point when it was interacting with a Queue, which was being populated by a library, in another thread.

In the simplest form, I was just doing

```
while not q.empty():
    row = q.get()
    # do something with row
```

The reason I had that, and no more (specifically leaving out `task_done`) was that I wasn't that experienced with multi-threading, or `Queue`s in python, and that's what was in the sample code.

In my situation, at some point after hours of operation, the app would hang, sometimes at `q.empty()`, sometimes at `q.get()`, and sometimes after `q.get()`.

When I read about others who'd had similar issues, it was only then that I learned about `task_done`, and when I added that to my code, simply like,

```
while not q.empty():
    row = q.get()
    # do something with row
    q.task_done()
```

These hangs I was experiencing ceased.  I do a few queueing operations like this throughout the app, and I want a standardised way to handle running through the q `while not q.empty()`, getting a row with `q.get()`, and calling `q.task_done()`.

Comment: Make sure you're using synchronized Queue.  get() will use the default (block=True, timeout=None) parameters, so it sounds like you may have a deadlock somewhere else.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get

Comment: And what should the corresponding put() be?  I don't have access to that, because it's in the library (although I could either request an update to there, or pass my own Queue subclass, and do what I want at put), but it's currently a simple q.put(data), and the Queue I've passed in was set to maxsize=0 (infinite), so I don't really know where the deadlock would have come from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The favourite method I've found for this, which I'm now using is a combination of a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) to handle the `get` and `task_done` like,

```
class read_from_q:
    def __init__(self, q, block=False, timeout=None):
        """
         :param Queue.Queue q:
         :param bool block:
         :param timeout:
        """
        self.q = q
        self.block = block
        self.timeout = timeout

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.q.get(self.block, self.timeout)

    def __exit__(self, _type, _value, _traceback):
        self.q.task_done()
```

in combination with a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to handle the `not empty()` check, and `yield` the row back to you like,

```
def queue_rows(q, block=False, timeout=None):
    """
     :param Queue.Queue q:
     :param bool block:
     :param int timeout:
    """
    while not q.empty():
        with read_from_q(q, block, timeout) as row:
            yield row
```

So now, instead of writing,

```
while not q.empty():
    row = q.get()
    # do something with row
    q.task_done()
```

I use,

```
for row in queue_rows(q):
    # do something with row and fogedaboutit
```

which I personally consider more elegant, and overall safer (because I won't forget about calling `task_done` as was the case before).